# on click of button is submitting the form

Tags: jquery, button, model-view-controller

I have 3 buttons in a from

```
<button type="button" name="N" id="N" value="N" class="btn">Add New Doc </button>
<button type="submit" name="submitButton" id="s1" value="AddMore" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button>
<button type="submit" name="submitButton" id="s2" value="SaveandSubmit" class="btn btn-success">Save and Submit</button>
```

two are for submitting the form and one is to add documents as below

[image]

"Add New doc" is  normal button when clicking that will create a new row for attaching a document jquery for that is as below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#N").click(function () {
        var index = (new Date()).getTime();
        var clone = $('#Newdoc').clone();
        clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/\[#\]/g, '[' + index + ']'));
        clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/"%"/g, '"' + index + '"'));
        var html = clone.html();
        $("#doc").append(clone.html());
    });
```

But when clicking this button a new row will added in the form and at the same time the form is going to submit.

**Edit**

**For testing purpose i changed all button type to "button" then also clicking any button is submitting the form**

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @SeanKwon clicking a type="button" should not submit the form..

Comment: can you please put full html of the page?

Comment: @sachu can you post more of your code? there may be another function causing issues unintentionally.

Comment: This probably won't solve your problem, but in the example jquery code you don't seem to be closing the `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: @Inkdot thanks for the input my colleague wrote an js file and in that he is submitting the for .btn class..i changed the button class in my view and its working normally..thanks for saving my time

Answer (score 0):

you can try attaching method in your button and return false.

html:

```
<button type="button" name="N" id="N" value="N" class="btn" onclick="addNewDoc();return false;">Add New Doc </button>
```

JS:

```
function addNewDoc(){
        var index = (new Date()).getTime();
        var clone = $('#Newdoc').clone();
        clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/\[#\]/g, '[' + index + ']'));
        clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/"%"/g, '"' + index + '"'));
        var html = clone.html();
        $("#doc").append(clone.html());            
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `event.preventDefault();`
instead of this:

```
$("#N").click(function () {
                var index = (new Date()).getTime();
```

Use:

```
 $("#N").click(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
 var index = (new Date()).getTime();
```

Comment: The button in question has no default form submission behavior from what I can see. How would this fix the problem?

Comment: same..no change..its submitting

Comment: Then i guess there is some other code in your HTML or JS that is causing this behaviour, kindly update your answer with relevant code. Thanks